# How do I access the `Constraint` kind properly?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, constraints, ghci, type-kinds

I'm playing around with the [`ConstraintKinds`](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-13-constraint-kinds.html) in GHCi. In the linked post I found a nice example:

```
type NoConstraint = (() :: Constraint)
```

But I can't get it to work. GHCi outputs the `Constraint` kind freely, not allowing me to use it at the same time. I. e. here's my full GHCi *session* (I'm not quite sure I know the right word; if there is a proper term I would appreciate the reader's edit):

```hs
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XConstraintKinds -XKindSignatures
Prelude> type NoConstraint = (() :: Constraint)

<interactive>:2:28: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Constraint'
    Perhaps you meant `NoConstraint' (line 2)
```

How do I access the `Constraint` kind properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constraint_kind.html), the `Constraint` kind needs to be imported from the `Data.Kind` module. See my GHCi session below:

```
Prelude> :set -XConstraintKinds -XKindSignatures
Prelude> type NoConstraint = (() :: Constraint)

<interactive>:2:28: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Constraint'
    Perhaps you meant `NoConstraint' (line 2)
Prelude> :m +Data.Kind
Prelude Data.Kind> type NoConstraint = (() :: Constraint)
Prelude Data.Kind>
```

Comment: I recommend [standalone kind signatures](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/poly_kinds.html#extension-StandaloneKindSignatures): `type NoConstraint :: Constraint; type NoConstraint = ()`.